# HTML: .jpg as a footer with repeat and a logo on it?

Tags: html, css

I have .jpg as footer that is 8x76 its just a simple line with height 76px and gradient blue color. I would like to put a logo on it. What's the best way to do that?

This is my CSS:

```
#light_footer_wrapper {
height: 110px;
background: url(../images/light_footer_repeat.jpg) repeat-x top left;
position: relative;
}

#light_footer_logo {
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
left: 600px;
height: 110px;  

}

#light_footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="light_footer_wrapper">
<div id="light_footer_logo"><img src="../a/images/logo.gif" /></div>
<div id="light_footer"></div>
```

I cant locate my logo now on my footer .jpg. but when I zoom in and out the logo moves around :S I want it locked

Comment: show your html for the footer region

Comment: Minimal HTML example would be helpful. By the way, for gradients it's better to use PNG-24 that usually provides much better quality and less file size than JPEG in case of gradients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also set a background-image of the logo for #light_footer if you didn't want an extra div, but an extra div might give you more control.

Comment: \o/ +1 because you suggesting him a better way :D

Answer (score 0):

`#light_footer_wrapper` is the full width of the browser, so when you resize, your logo will move with it.

You should put the image inside of `#light_footer`, make `#light_footer` `position:relative`, and then tweak your `left` and `top` values on `#light_footer_logo`.